# Unable to properly pass arguments with spaces to a PowerShell script from Jenkins

Tags: powershell, shell, jenkins

I have a stage in a Jenkins pipeline where I call a PowerShell script which I do within a container and I call it like this:

```
    stage('Processing') {
            container('remote') {
                sh "pwsh -file script.ps1 ${params.NAME} ${params.DESCRIPTION} ${params.PEOPLE} 
            }
    }
```

Within the script I do some preparation for a remote session and I call it using this command

```
Invoke-Command -Session $RemoteSession -ArgumentList $parameters -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock
```

The mentioned preparation is basically me adding another parameter to args which I do like this

```
    $parameters = @()
    $parameters = $parameters + $args
    $parameters += $var
```

Within the scriptblock I reference the args by their index like $args[1]. These are primarily strings, and everything works when an argument passed from Jenkins has no spaces in it. But when let's say ${params.NAME} has a space in it, but the indexing does not work correctly as spaces separate the original string into multiple arguments, hence the if the original index was $args[1], instead of taking in the value of ${params.DESCRIPTION}, it takes in a part of ${params.NAME}.

Do you know how to avoid this issue and take in the parameters with the original indexing even if it has spaces in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To make PowerShell see the expanded values such as `${params.NAME}` as a single argument each, enclose them in `"`, which in the context of the `"..."` Groovy string must be escaped as `\"`

Therefore:

```
sh "pwsh -File script.ps1 \"${params.NAME}\" \"${params.DESCRIPTION}\" \"${params.PEOPLE}\""
```

Comment: If I run the line above put but "pwsh" right before referencing the file (./script.ps1), the args are perceived as expected and the run was fully successful. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Glad to hear it, @BlackShark; my pleasure. Note that `pwsh script.ps1 ...` and `pwsh -File script.ps1 ...` (as now shown in the answer) should work the same, because `-File` is the default parameter.